# Высокие нагрузки и на слабом сервере

Tags: c++, производительность

**Дано:**

1) слабый сервер

2) 10 000 компьютеров

3) материал на каждом компьютере (например видео по 2-3 часа)

**Найти:**

Решение, при котором можно передавать материал, стабильно со всех машин.

Ограничение по времени - отсутствует.

**Как лучше это реализовать?**

Мой опыт подсказывает, что http протокол тут не пойдет. Ибо при большой передаче данных, всё просто рухнет.

Думаю оптимальный вариант использовать TCP. Вообщем, послушаю мнение более опытных коллег. =)

Comment: У вас взаимное исключение: "высокие нагрузки" и одновременно с этим "ограничение по времени отсутствует". Коль скоро ограничения по времени нет - можно подключаться ко всем машинам по очереди и качать хоть через модем 2400 бит в секунду.

Comment: можно написать клиент-серверную часть. клиент будет отправлять серверу какие то данные. и при таком подходе можно контролировать количество отправляемых пакетов,  клиент будет смотреть на загрузку системы и будет отправлять исходя из загрузки

Comment: видео 2-3 часа - это как минимум гигабайт (ок, допустим видео очень плохого качества и это 250мб). Сумарный объем данных - 10 терабайт (2.5терабайта). Если сеть 1гигабит, то это 100мб в секунду - 28 часов (7 для плохого качества).  Но ещё есть диск... Вы точно сделали рассчеты?

Comment: Странно, что TCP вам подходит, а HTTP нет (который через тот же TCP работает). А FTP например как вам смотрится?

Comment: Используйте модель торрент трекера, пусть видео подгружаются с уже скаченых клиентов. Тут узкое место будет сетевая магистраль.

Comment: > Странно, что TCP вам подходит, а HTTP нет >>>TCP может одновременно работать со всеми по кусочку, а http пока все не загрузит не отключится.

Comment: Посмотрите на DC и любые р2р

Comment: @hitcode HTTP может работать и по кусочку, и в паралель. и много-много ещё как. Если бы это  было не так, то апач (веб сервер) не работал бы.

Comment: Если вам нужна "одновременная" и "паралельная"  рассылка - вам нужен UDP протокол.

Comment: Куда передавать, на сервер?

Comment: опишите более детально: где лежат данные изначально, кто инициирует передачу (как авторизуетесь), как часто повторять передачу данных, что такое слабый сервер (что мешает обойти по N клиентов за раз, если сервер инициирует передачу? Или что мешает не принимать новых соединений, если сервер загружен и соединения инициирует клиент?). Что является узким местом в вашем случае: пропускная способность сети сервера, скорости дисков на сервере? память на сервере? CPU?